# Activate Onchange function with VBA in URL

Tags: excel, vba, visibility, onchange

I have to fill forms inside a web site using excel. 
The site works like this - when choosing something from a combobox then new input boxes are activated with onchange function as below code.

```html
<select name="murat" id="murat" class="normalText" onchange="muratonChange(this);">
```

```js
function muratonChange(source) {
  var muratIndex, Visibility;
  muratIndex=source.selectedIndex
  document.all.ayaz.style.visibility="visible";
```

I can select anything inside combobox. However, input boxes are not becoming visible so I cannot change them.
Using below vba code to assign value to combobox

```
While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = ie.document.querySelector("murat")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        If Not ele Is Nothing Then
            ele.Click                            
            ie.document.getElementsByName("murat")(0).Value = Application.VLookup(Sheets("fener").Range("D3").Text, Sheets("bahce").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
        End If
```

Comment: can you share the url or is the page behind a login? And have you tried parentWindow.execScript to fire the function or attach an htmlevent for change and dispatch it?

Comment: actually site is behind login and also behind the corporate firewall.  I have changed name of items. by the way, I did not tried parentWindow.execScript to fire the function. just tried to find fireevent "onChange" and cant succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First please make comment and help instead of editting my english grammar to earn badges etc.
thanks to user @QHarr. I followed his foot steps. below code is solved my problem.

```
        Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy: Set CurrentWindow = ie.document.parentWindow
        Call CurrentWindow.execScript("muratonChange(this)")
```